# Test error:MyActivity has already set content. If you have populated the Activity with a ComposeView, make sure to call setContent on that ComposeView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

When running Robolectric unit tests with the latest version of Compose 1.2.0, then the tests using `createAndroidComposeRule` fail with the following error:

> MyActivity has already set content. If you have populated the Activity with a ComposeView, make sure to call setContent on that ComposeView instead of on the test rule; and make sure that that call to `setContent {}` is done after the ComposeTestRule has run

Code from one of the failing tests:

```
composeTestRule.setContent {
    Column {
        Text(textTitle)
        DemoScopedInjectedViewModelComposable()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looking carefully, the error message helps a lot, even though it's talking about a `ComposeView` instead of an `Activity`. But according to it:

```kotlin
composeTestRule.setContent { ... }
```

should be changed to:

```kotlin
composeTestRule.activity.setContent { ... }
```

and the tests should run without this error occurring anymore.

Comment: I read the error message carefully and it didn't help but your answer fixed the error.

Answer (score 7):

Compose with 1.2 has [forbidden](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1988912) to overwrite the content of the activity rule. But this can be still done with setting content directly on activity, not activity test rule.

The easiest way to solve this issue is to set content not on the activity rule but on the activity itself. It can be done like this:

```
composeTestRule.activity.runOnUiThread {
    composeTestRule.activity.setContent {
        Column {
            Text(textTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

To simplify usage you can use following extension

```
fun <R : TestRule, A : ComponentActivity> AndroidComposeTestRule<R, A>.setContentOnActivity(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    this.activity.runOnUiThread {
        this.activity.setContent {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to fetch the Compose View from the Activity (the Activity is available in the test rule), and then call `setContent` on that View instead of directly on the test rule, as the error message indicates.

Here is a test helper function I created to avoid this problem in my tests:

```
fun AndroidComposeTestRule<ActivityScenarioRule<MyActivity>, MyActivity>.clearAndSetContent(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    (this.activity.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)?.getChildAt(0) as? ComposeView)?.setContent(content)
        ?: this.setContent(content)
}
```

Updated test:

```
composeTestRule.clearAndSetContent {
    Column {
        Text(textTitle)
        DemoScopedInjectedViewModelComposable()
    }
}
```

For reference this is my test rule:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MyActivity>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ComponentActivity` instead of `MainActivity` while setting the `composeTestRule` worked for me:

```
class MainActivityInstrumentedTest {

    // @get:Rule
    // val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()
    
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

}
```